# how to clone UIComponents added dynamically in a Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, adobe, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I am facing an issue in cloning of UIComponents added dynamically in Canvas to another Canvas.

I follow this example but It doesn't work for components added dynamically because childDescriptors become null in this senario.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="horizontal">
     <mx:Script>
          <![CDATA[
               private function cloneButton_clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void
               {
                    var childDescriptors:Array = original.childDescriptors;
                    var descriptorsCount:int = childDescriptors.length;
                    for (var i:int; i < descriptorsCount; i++)
                    {
                         cloned.createComponentFromDescriptor(original.childDescriptors[i],
                                                                       false);
                    }
                    cloned.validateNow();
               }
          ]]>
     </mx:Script>
     <mx:Button label="Clone Canvas" click="cloneButton_clickHandler(event);" />
     <mx:Canvas id="original" width="100" height="100" borderStyle="solid" >
          <mx:Label text="Some Label" />
          <mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{['data1', 'data2']}" bottom="0" />
     </mx:Canvas>
     <mx:Canvas id="cloned" width="100" height="100" borderStyle="solid" >

     </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never cloned objects with childDescriptors but you might try to do the cloning before the descriptors are set to null, or at least copying the descriptors before that.

The descriptors are likely set to null as part of the process of instantiating MXML objects. So you should be able to get the the descriptors before that happens.

Try using the "initialize" or even "preinitialize" event that will be dispatched by the object you wish to clone the children of.